# Using generics to pass class type from method to method

Tags: java, generics, types

In a game that I am writing currently, I have a list of `Collectable` objects in my inventory.When I activate one of theses objects , some need another `Collectable` object to work upon.Now , in my UI , I show all the possible candidate `Collectable` objects that the original object might work upon.To do this, I check if an object IS-A instanceof an interface.But that interface varies from object to object.This UI is called `ItemSelector` and is called by the main UI.

I construct the `ItemSelector` by making the constructor take a `class<T> selectionCriteria` as a parameter.

```
<T> ItemSelector(Class<T> selectionCriteria){
     // ... Do work.
}
```

However, that means that when I create an object of this class, I have to specifically hardcode all the different possible interfaces possible in a `switch case` statement according to the type of the original object.What I want to do is that have a method in each of the `Collectable` object (the `Collectable` interface will have a `getSelectionCriteriaInterface()` method that will be overriden by the concrete classes) that will return the interface it uses as the selectionCriteria.

How do I achieve this.
Hoping for a speedy reply,
Thanks.

Comment: Show us more code, hard to imagine what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
interface Collectable {
    ...
    Class<?> getSelectionCriteriaInterface();
}
```

Possible implemention:

```
public Class<?> getSelectionCriteriaInterface() {
    return MyInterface.class;
}
```

Then when checking, something like:

```
Collection<Collectable> allItems = ...;
Collectable c = ...;

List<Collectable> filtered = allItems.stream()
    .filter(c.getSelectionCriteriaInterface()::isInstance)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```